# How to delay a command execution until the next hmode?

Tags: luatex, tex-core, paragraphs

I want to write an environment which adds a marginnote at the begin. The problem is that I can't control the content of the enviroment and so the placement of the marginnote varies a lot. How could I delay the command to the first text line so that the Text moves to the wanted position? A lualatex solution would be ok (and interesting).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newenvironment{myenv}{\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}Text}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
abc
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
\vspace{2cm}
abc\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}wanted pos}
\end{myenv}


\begin{myenv}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item abc\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}wanted pos}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just a shoot in the darkness (well, you probably considered it somehow or it's a true nonsense): `\everypar`?

Comment: @tohecz: I tried `\everypar` but got (with the margin note) an memory exceeded error. With simple text `\everypar` works for the normal text but is lost in the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this just uses local settings so can (will) go wrong if the next paragraph starts in a local group as things won't get restored properly. That's fixable but this shows the basic idea...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\let\zzeverypar\everypar
\newtoks\everypar
\zzeverypar{\the\everypar}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
\ifvmode
\zzeverypar\expandafter{\the\zzeverypar\zzeverypar{\the\everypar}\z}%
\else
\z
\fi
}
{}

\def\z{\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}Text}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
abc
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
\vspace{2cm}
abc\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}wanted pos}
\end{myenv}


\begin{myenv}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item abc\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][r]{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}wanted pos}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like a job of `l3galley` :-)

Comment: @JosephWright yes that was my thought too (even though I didn't use it here:-)

Comment: This doesn't work for the list, there the marker is lost (this is probably one of the examples of "(will) go wrong if the next paragraph starts in a local group" ;-(). And this is naturally the main problematic case. I can tell people not to start a paragraph with `{\bfseries ..` and suggest alternatives but I don't see how to avoid lists at the begin of the environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah yes well that is because lists use exactly the same trick to add the list item label, I could make the two cooperate, I suppose...

Comment: in general it's hard (I considered doing this to stop `\color` messing up spacing if used in vmode, but there were too many special cases). As Joseph indicated this is the problem l3galley solves but does it by taking control of vertical list completely so is more or less incompatible with everything not written for that.

Comment: That's why I was thinking about a lualatex solution. I hoped it wouldn't interfere with all the everypar hacks. Btw: the marginnote doesn't need to be the first thing in the paragraph. Somewhere in the first line would work too.

Comment: updated with private everypar to avoid trashing lists

Comment: Sorry I nearly missed the update. This looks ok.

Comment: oops I forgot the @UlrikeFischer ping in the last comment:-)